# Antd apply Tooltip to Menu.Item on non collapsed Sider

Tags: css, reactjs, antd

I'm trying to replicate a collapsed `Sider` without declaring `collapsed={true}` purely to have the tooltip effect.

The issue is that when I wrap `Menu.Item` within a `Tooltip` it seems that it is no longer defined and the special trigger is not appearing

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import "./index.css";
import { Layout, Menu, Icon, Tooltip } from "antd";
import { sidebar } from "./nav";

const { Header, Sider, Content } = Layout;

class SiderDemo extends React.Component {
  state = {
    collapsed: false
  };

  toggle = () => {
    this.setState({
      collapsed: !this.state.collapsed
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Layout>
        <Sider trigger={null} collapsible collapsedWidth="0" breakpoint="sm">
          <div className="logo" />
          <Menu theme="dark" mode="inline" defaultSelectedKeys={["1"]}>
            {sidebar.map(menu => (
              <Tooltip placement="right" title={menu.name}>
                <Menu.Item
                  style={{ borderRadius: 2, width: "72px" }}
                  item={menu.name}
                  key={menu.key}
                >
                  <Icon type={menu.icon} />
                </Menu.Item>
              </Tooltip>
            ))}
          </Menu>
        </Sider>
        <Layout>
          <Header style={{ background: "#fff", padding: 0 }}>
            <Icon
              className="trigger"
              type={this.state.collapsed ? "menu-unfold" : "menu-fold"}
              onClick={this.toggle}
            />
          </Header>
          <Content
            style={{
              margin: "24px 16px",
              padding: 24,
              background: "#fff",
              minHeight: 280
            }}
          >
            Content
          </Content>
        </Layout>
      </Layout>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<SiderDemo />, document.getElementById("container"));
```

[image: Edit serverless-water-lnjem]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move your `tooltip` inside and wrap the `Menu.Item`'s `Icon`. I found this is the quickest way to do it.

[image: menu-item-tooltip]

```
   {sidebar.map(menu => (
              <Menu.Item
                style={{ borderRadius: 2, width: "72px" }}
                item={menu.name}
                key={menu.key}
              >
                <Tooltip
                  placement="right"
                  title={menu.name}
                  className="tooltip"
                >
                  <div className="my-icon-wrapper test">
                    <Icon type={menu.icon} />
                  </div>
                </Tooltip>
              </Menu.Item>
            ))}
```

**css**

```
.my-icon-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.test {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: I know that works, however, the reason I asked is that I want the tooltip to appear when hovering over Menu.Item, not the icon.

Comment: @Freddy. I updated the code. was that what you were looking for?

Comment: Hey, how did you record the gif? Which OS you using?

Comment: I use "ScreenToGif".I am on windows 10.

Comment: @blueseal seems like tooltip stops working when you hover on different screen size

Comment: what do you mean different screen size? I checked for 600px widescreen. It was still working.

Comment: If you let says view it on 400-320px webview and hover over the menu item it seems that the tooltip does not appear you physically have to click on it in order for it to show

Answer (score 0):

Currently, your code just won't work because `Menu` requires its children **to be only** of type `Menu.Item`.

Therefore, you need to add a wrapper with the same `width` as the `Menu.Item`.

[image]

```
//    v remove the trigger={null} for trigger to appear
<Sider collapsible collapsedWidth="0" breakpoint="sm">


<Menu theme="dark" mode="inline" defaultSelectedKeys={['1']}>
  {sidebar.map(menu => (
    <Menu.Item item={menu.name} key={menu.key}>
      <Tooltip placement="right" title={menu.name}>
//                       v Wrapper
        <div style={{ width: '100%' }}>
          <Icon type={menu.icon} />
        </div>
      </Tooltip>
    </Menu.Item>
  ))}
</Menu>
```

[image: Edit Q-59085357-MenuTooltip]

Comment: Ah I see. Dennis could you also answer why the special trigger icon does not appear on the sidebar?

Comment: I don't understand which special trigger you referring to

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/31j2kjyo0q when collapsedWidth=0 on breakpoint the trigger should appear

Comment: because you set `trigger={null}`, check the updated sandbox

Comment: Ah, I didn't see that. seems like tooltip stops working when you hover on different screen size.

Comment: Can't guess what appears, but it sounds like a discussion for other question, feel free upvoting if the answer was helpful.

Comment: If you let says view it on 400-320px webview and hover over the menu item it seems that the tooltip does not appear you physically have to click on it in order for it to show